# How to convert numbers from an image to a csv file using python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am trying to extract the words and numbers from this image:

[image]

my desired output is a csv table that directly imitates the table in the image.

Current code:

```
import cv2
import os,argparse
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

ap=argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i","--image",
                required=True,
                help="Path to the image folder")
ap.add_argument("-p","--pre_processor",
                default="thresh", 
                help="the preprocessor usage")
args=vars(ap.parse_args())
 
images=cv2.imread(args["image"])
 
#convert to grayscale image
gray=cv2.cvtColor(images, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
 
#checking whether thresh or blur
if args["pre_processor"]=="thresh":
    cv2.threshold(gray, 0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY| cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
if args["pre_processor"]=="blur":
    cv2.medianBlur(gray, 3)
     

filename = "{}.bmp".format(os.getpid())
cv2.imwrite(filename, gray)
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(filename), config='--psm 7')
os.remove(filename)
print(text)
 
#cv2.imshow("Image Input", images)
#cv2.imshow("Output In Grayscale", gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

processed image output:

[image]

My output is currently:

```
: RF
```

Is there anything obvious i am doing wrong? Is the blur from the words and numbers on the image too difficult to parse?

Comment: I take it that's the original image, correct? What does the actual image being passed to pytesseract look like?

Comment: Correct, I have updated code to show processed image.

Comment: I'm not very experienced in this area, but I have read that black text on a light background is often easier for OCR. I'd try inverting the  grayscale of the images.

Comment: After that you may want to try a threshold to use to binarize the images. I thought your code was already doing that, but apparently it isn't.